# How to split a string

Tags: sql-server

How do I convert the following c# to ms sql?

```
#region determine if Dimension has length & width
decimal _dimension = 0;
string[] xy = new string[1];
Dimension = Dimension.ToUpper();
if (Dimension.Contains('X'))
{
    xy = Dimension.Split('X');
    _dimension = (Convert.ToInt32(xy[0]) * Convert.ToInt32(xy[1]) / 144);
}
else
{
        _dimension = Convert.ToDecimal(Dimension);
}
#endregion


DECLARE @_dimension numeric
select @_dimension = Dimension
```

how to upcase string?

how to split string at 'X'?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have SQL that isn't working as intended?  Otherwise, all this says to me is that you're too lazy to attempt it yourself and want us to figure it out for you.

Comment: Questions that don't demonstrate some effort on your part tend to cause negative reactions from our community. In the future, please post your attempt, or at least explain why you're stuck at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The `.ToUpper` you use here is replaced by the T-SQL function `UPPER()`, and the `.Contains` can be replaced with something like `CHARINDEX('X', YourString)` to return the location of "X" - if it's greater than zero, then it's the place in the string where it appears. There's no equivalent for the `.Split()` function per se, but you could do a `CHARINDEX()` to find the first "X", then to do another to find the next "X", and then take the difference and do a `SUBSTRING()` to get just that smaller string from your larger input.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

- String splitting tutorial: http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/09/sql-function-split.html
- Another SO question: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)
- Alternative implementation: http://tim.mackey.ie/SQLStringSplitFunction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can;

```
select 
    case when (@_dimension like '%x%') then 
        (cast(left(@_dimension, charindex('X', @_dimension, 1) - 1) as int)
        *
        cast(substring(@_dimension, 1 + charindex('X', @_dimension, 1), len(@_dimension)) as int)) / 144.00
    else
        cast(@_dimension as decimal(10, 5))
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

for splitting you need to create your own T-SQL function as the one showed below:

> CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT ( @str_in VARCHAR(8000), @separator VARCHAR(4) )
>   RETURNS @strtable TABLE (strval VARCHAR(8000)) AS BEGIN
>
> DECLARE @Occurrences INT, @Counter INT, @tmpStr VARCHAR(8000)
>
> SET @Counter = 0 IF SUBSTRING(@str_in,LEN(@str_in),1) <> @separator
>   SET @str_in = @str_in + @separator
>
> SET @Occurrences =
>   (DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@str_in,@separator,@separator+'#')) -
>   DATALENGTH(@str_in))/ DATALENGTH(@separator) SET @tmpStr = @str_in
>
> WHILE @Counter <= @Occurrences BEGIN SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
>   INSERT INTO @strtable VALUES (
>   SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,1,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)-1))
>
> SET @tmpStr = SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,CHARINDEX(@separator,@tmpStr)+1,8000)
>
> IF DATALENGTH(@tmpStr) = 0 BREAK
>
> END RETURN END